# Override AntD component style with LESS

Tags: css, less, antd

I suspect this is more of a LESS question and may not be specific to Ant Design other than the way they implemented some of their components is preventing me from overriding or extending the styles.

Specifically, I want to change the font size and weight for the title area of the PageHeader component.  Unfortunately, the component's style does not use the LESS variables defined in the default.less theme for these two settings.  The source code can be found here: https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/blob/master/components/page-header/style/index.less

I have no issues changing the color, for instance, or any other variables defined in the theme but I am new to LESS and not sure how to go about overriding the styles defined for an individual component like this. Oh, and I don't want to use inline styles. We use this component in many places in our application, so I want to define the overrides in one place, once and have them be global for the application (like I can do with the theme variables).

So, how do I override the font-weight and font-size styles defined on lines 45 and 46 of the referenced file?

Comment: just override the cas class

Comment: Where? How? Everything we've tried has failed to make a difference.

Comment: Can you please make https://codesandbox.io/s/new of desired input, output and I will show you.

Comment: Easier said than done. I would have to recreate the entire solution to get everything involved setup correctly (per https://ant.design/docs/react/customize-theme).  And, as I mentioned, we have been directed NOT to use inline styles as these changes need to be done globally.  If the solution can't be described simply, then I suspect our governance board won't go for it.

Comment: You don't have to recreate all your project... just showing one component... anyways I added my answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here an example of how I have done it in my project:

### Using .css file

Override the CSS class by `.css/.scss` and so on:

```
// Main layout where all antd componets used.
import './MyLayout.css';
```

```css
/* MyLayout.css */
.ant-tooltip-inner {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
}
```

Here I reversed all tooltips (default are black).

[image: White Tooltips]

### Using Styled-Components

Same like above just as `CSS-JS`:

```js
const LayoutStyled = styled(Layout)`
  height: 100vh;
  * {
    font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen,
      Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
  }

  .ant-layout-sider-light .ant-layout-sider-trigger {
    border-right: 1px solid ${HCOLOR.border};
  }
`;
```

Here I overrode all fonts and added the right border to antd sider trigger (default no border).

[image: Trigger with border]

---

### Conclusion

Find the **css-class / css-property** with dev-tools (`Ctrl+Shift+C` in Chrome) and override it as you like.

Comment: It appears our problem was the location of the overrides. Once we put them were they were associated with the main layout of the app, the overrides were applied.  I'm making this as the answer pending a review by our governance board to make sure they are okay with overriding the CSS classes rather than the source LESS variables (as was the original question).

Answer (score 0):

Use `less` files to apply the styling as mentioned in the antd docs [here](https://pro.ant.design/docs/style/).